# Please paraphrase the bold sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The MacDonald’s franchise **offers just one prominent case of a corporation fighting to guide its brand through these difficult situations.**

Comment: Is there something specific you don’t understand?

Comment: The combination of *offers just one prominent case of a corporation fighting *

Comment: According to the Oxford dictionary, offer a battle or fighting means to give sb an opportunity for a battle; with this in mind, I cannot figure out the meaning of the sentence above. Please comment on that.

Comment: Fighting here just means trying or making an effort.

Answer (score 1):

Paraphrasing: "Many corporations are struggling in this difficult situation. McDonald's is an example of such a corporation."